# Monotouch framework in existing objective-c app

Tags: iphone, sdk, xamarin.ios

I would like to use my existing objective-c UI layer, but call on a few monotouch functions from objective-c.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as MonoTouch is a totally separate development environment.

MonoTouch compiles you code into an iPhone application.

A MonoTouch application however does have complete access to the iPhone API.